# Unable to write data to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting an error message while writing to csv! The data i get from my code:

```
#STD by row:
df.std()
print(df.std())

Latitude                          0.001138
Longitude                         0.000830
Altitude                          0.757706
Velocity_north                    1.085603
Velocity_east                     0.926185
```

I'm trying to write this output data to a csv:

```
# writing to csv file
fields = ['RTK', 'IMU']
filename = "C:\\Users\\Read.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv dict writer object
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    # writing data rows
    writer.writerows(df.std())
```

Comment: what is the error message? did you try assigning the writer variable: writer = csv.writer(csvfile)?

Comment: You have ````writer```` instead of ````csvwriter```` on the bottom line

Answer (score 4):

You may use the df.to_csv() method of pandas for to write your dataframe in csv file.
I made a code example with your informations that i use when i need to convert a dataframe in csv file:

```
new_df = df.std() 
compression_opts = dict(method = 'zip',archive_name = 'Read.csv')
new_df.to_csv('Read.zip',index=False,compression=compression_opts)
```

if you need more informations about, see this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: thank you Thales! but I'm getting an error message: compression=compression_opts)
TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'compression'